# Understanding intersect and difference of dictionaries in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am new to python and came across this problem as  english is not my native language so I am having a little trouble with this problem but wrote my code as of what I understand from this question  can anyone tell if I am right and if not please improve my code or give your's

*Assume you are given two dictionaries d1 and d2, each with integer keys and integer values. You are also given a function f, that takes in two integers, performs an unknown operation on them, and returns a value.*

*Write a function called dict_interdiff that takes in two dictionaries (d1 and d2). The function will return a tuple of two dictionaries: a dictionary of the intersect of d1 and d2 and a dictionary of the difference of d1 and d2, calculated as follows:*

*'''**Intersect**: The keys to the intersect dictionary 
are keys that are common in both d1 and d2.
To get the values of the intersect dictionary,
look at the common keys in d1 and d2 and applythe
functionf to these keys' values -- the value 
of the common key in d1 is the first parameterto the 
function and the value of the common key in d2
is the second parameter to the function. 
Do not implement f inside your dict_interdiff code --
assume it is defined outside.*

***Difference***: a key-value pair in the difference dictionary is
(a) every key-value pair 
in d1 whose key appears only in d1 and not in d2 or (b) every
key-value pair in d2 whose 
key appears only in d2 and not in d1.'''

Here are two examples:*

```
'''If f(a, b) returns a + b
d1 = {1:30, 2:20, 3:30, 5:80}
d2 = {1:40, 2:50, 3:60, 4:70, 6:90}
then dict_interdiff(d1, d2) 
returns ({1: 70, 2: 70, 3: 90}, {4: 70, 5: 80, 6: 90})


If f(a, b) returns a > b
d1 = {1:30, 2:20, 3:30}
d2 = {1:40, 2:50, 3:60}
then dict_interdiff(d1, d2)
returns ({1: False, 2: False, 3: False}, {})'''
```

**Here is my code** :

```
def dict_interdiff(d1, d2):

a=d1.keys()
b=d2.keys()
c=d1.values()
d=d2.values()
e=()
u={}
f=[]
g=[]
for i in range(max(a,b)):
    if a[i]==b[i]:
        u=f(a[i],b[i])
    elif a[i] not in b:
         t=c.find(a[i])
         f.append(c[t])
         g.append(a[i])
         k=dict(zip(g,f))
    elif b[i] not in a:
         t=c.find(b[i])
         f.append(d[t])
         g.append(b[i])
         k=dict(zip(g,f))
    e+(u,)+(k,)
return e
```

Moreover I cannot check my code because it given to assume that f is defined and I don't know that and hence cannot run in my interpreter

Comment: I just defined `f`: `def f(a, b): return a + b`, and it didn't work: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 30, in <module>
    print(dict_interdiff({1:30, 2:20, 3:30, 5:80}, {1:40, 2:50, 3:60, 4:70, 6:90}))
  File "test.py", line 14, in dict_interdiff
    for i in range(max(a,b)):
TypeError: range() integer end argument expected, got list.`

Comment: @zondo can you improve my code or can you give your's solution

Comment: I don't think I can.  I tried to fix that problem by saying `max(len(a), len(b))` instead of `max(a, b)`, but I then got another error that I didn't know how to fix.

Comment: you are looking at these dicts as though they are arrays, which is not a helpful approach. Dicts are hashes - keys and associated values. Consider those keys might be ANYTHING rather than integers, and you can see why the accessor is failing.  See the example solution below...

Comment: The difference is  the symmetric-difference if you want the unique keys from both a and b

Comment: @PadraicCunningham can you please simplify your question as it is too technical for me and sorry to say but I don't know what hashable means

Comment: @jamessmith, it does not matter, I just saw you are only dealing  with numbers, basically all you want is `d1.viewkeys() & d2` t get the intersecting keys and and `d1.viwekeys() ^ d2` to get the symmetric difference

Comment: @PadraicCunningham so can you help me solve this problem?and please put it in code I am slow at reading and understanding code like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it all using set operations on the dicts:

```
def dict_interdiff(d1, d2):
    # symmetric difference, keys in either d1 or d2 but not both.
    sym_diff = d1.viewkeys() ^ d2
    # intersection, keys that are common to both d1 and d2.
    intersect = d1.viewkeys() & d2
    # apply f on values of the keys that common to both dicts.
    a = {k: f(d1[k], d2[k]) for k in intersect}
    b = {k: d1[k] for k in sym_diff & d1.viewkeys()}
    # add key/value pairings from d2 using keys that appear in sym_diff 
    b.update({k: d2[k] for k in sym_diff & d2.viewkeys()})
    return a,b
```

`sym_diff = d1.viewkeys() ^ d2` gets the [Symmetric_difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference) i.e the keys that are in *either* `a` or `b` but *not in both*.

`intersect = d1.viewkeys() & d2` gets the [intersection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersection_(set_theory))  of the keys i.e keys that appear *in both* d1 and d2.

`b = {k: d1[k] for k in sym_diff.viewkeys() & d1}` creates a dict of comprising of the keys  from d1 that appear in the sym_diff set.

`b.update({k: d2[k] for k in sym_diff.viewkeys() & d2})` updates b adding the key/value pairings from d2, using the keys that appear in `sym_diff` so you end up with a dict `b` that has all the keys from the `sym_diff` set and their values.

Comment: Thanks it works but for dict_interdiff({1: 2}, {2: 1}) it returned `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "submission.py", line 5, in dict_interdiff
    a = {k:f(d1[k],d2[k]) for k in sym_diff}
  File "submission.py", line 5, in <dictcomp>
    a = {k:f(d1[k],d2[k]) for k in sym_diff}
KeyError: 1`

Comment: @jamessmith, yes, see the eddit

Comment: sorry for taking your time but can you explain what your code is doing (I am new  and slow at reading code)

Comment: @jamessmith, sure I will add some explanation in a sec

Comment: @ Padraic Cunningham thank you very much (that's what I love about this community it helps till the end ) and great people  like you makes it so.Thanks again

Comment: @jamessmith, no prob, you're welcome, if there is anything that is still unclear feel free to ask.

Comment: @ Padraic Cunningham there is nothing unclear about this question you explained it all very well.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Seems pretty straightforward, based on the differences.

```
def dict_interdiff(d1, d2, f):
  sameKeys = set(d1.keys()) & set(d2.keys())  # Keys in both dicts
  same     = dict([(k, f(d1[k],d2[k])) for k in sameKeys])  # f applied
  diffKeys = set(d1.keys())^set(d2.keys())   # Keys in single dict
  diffs    = dict([(k,d1.get(k, d2.get(k))) for k in diffKeys])  # values
  return (same,diffs,)
```

I suppose I should share confirmation it delivered expected results!

```
>>> dict_interdiff(d1, d2, f)
({1: 70, 2: 70, 3: 90}, {4: 70, 5: 80, 6: 90})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always check your code by defining it yourself in the file. Here's my simple implementation:

```
def dict_interdiff(d1, d2):
'''
d1, d2: dicts whose keys and values are integers
Returns a tuple of dictionaries according to the instructions above
'''
# Your code here
orderedintersect={}
ordereddiff={}
done=d1.copy()
dtwo=d2.copy()
for key in done:
    if key in dtwo:
        orderedintersect[key]=f(done[key],dtwo[key])
        del d1[key]
        del d2[key]
d1.update(d2)
for i in sorted(d1.keys()):
    ordereddiff[i]=d1[i]
return orderedintersect,ordereddiff   

def f(a,b):
    return a+b
```